# arduino is skipping the if statement

Tags: motor, pins

Hi guys I am new to this language and i just tested the code to control a servo motor
Can anybody help me please ? here is the code

```
void setup() {

  servo_test.attach(3);      
  pinMode(9, INPUT);

}

void loop() {

 if ( digitalRead (9 == HIGH)) {

   for(angle = 0; angle < 180; angle += 5)    to 180 degrees 
  {                                  
    servo_test.write(angle);                
    delay(5);                       
  } 

  delay(4000);
  for(angle = 180; angle>=1; angle-=5)      to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    servo_test.write(angle);               specified angle
    delay(5);                       
  } 

    delay(4000);
}

}
```

It is just like the arduino completely ignore the if statement and start the loop wheter pin 9 is in high or low state  even if  i wire it directly to gnd

Comment: Try digitalRead(9)==HIGH

Answer (score 0):

In your code this line:

```
 if ( digitalRead (9 == HIGH)) {
```

...is likely passing the function "digitalRead()" the value zero as "9 == HIGH" is likely false.

Likely what you want to do is check if the value returned by the function "digitalRead()" is high.  Try:

```
 if ( digitalRead (9) == HIGH) {
```

...instead.

Comment: Yeah, that line is wrong. That code evaluates as `if (digitalRead(0))`, which returns the value of pin 0. Not sure how LOW is defined in the Arduino IDE. If it's 0 then you'll get false if pin 0 is `==LOW` and true if the pin is `==HIGH`.

Comment: so Arduino SE becomes a typo correction site. this answer is not useful

Comment: @Juraj I don't think it's a typo. It's a newbie's syntax error that compiles. I'm sure the answer was quite useful to the OP.